# Is there a way to form a sequence of intervals s.t they cover all the rational numbers in $(0,1)$ in a way that $C_n \subset Int(C_{n+1}),$

Tags: rational-numbers, set-partition

Is there a way to form a sequence of intervals $C_i \subset \mathbb{R} $ such that they cover all the rational numbers in $(0,1)$ in a way that 
$$C_n \subset Int(C_{n+1}),$$
where $C_i$ is closed.

Note: It is the standard topology.

Comment: What topology are you using?  Are the $C_i$ sets of rationals or intervals?

Comment: You insist that $C_i$ be a partition, so they must be disjoint, but you also insist on some containment relation. One has to give way.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг See my edit, please.

Comment: @RossMillikan See my edit, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you just need a set of nested closed intervals with union $(0,1)$.  You can just have $ C_i=[\frac 1{i+3},1-\frac 1{i+3}]$ for example.  Then to form a partition of the rationals just take the rationals in $C_{i+1}\setminus C_i$

Answer (score 0):

Yes: $$C_n = \left[\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right].$$

This answers the question in the body, not the question in the title - the $C_n$ do not form a partition, since they are not disjoint (indeed, the condition $C_n\subset Int(C_{n+1})$ implies they cannot be disjoint).

Comment: A quibble:  this doesn't work well for $n=1$ or $2$